# Stream system audio to web browser (javascript) over network

Tags: javascript, linux, webrtc, web-audio-api, jack

I'm searching if is possible to bring up an environment made by 1 PC and 1 smartphone:

1. PC1 running without screen and with JACK audio server  (or alsa or whatever)
2. smartphone connected to the same network of PC1 and with the browser pointing to http://pc1/

Is possible to stream PC1'system audio on the smartphone's WebBrowser?
Anyone can explain me how? Both in server-side (Linux/Jackd) and in client-side (Javascript on WebBrowser with Audio API)

Regards

Comment: If there's no browser on 1) then you'll need C++ WebRTC native or similar

Comment: Cannot I use Jackd to do that? Have you got some example to share?

Comment: Who is actually the source of audio? What you wanna do in layman terms? You can for example stream from a nodejs server to the browser (i.e. an mp3 playlist)

Comment: The audio source is the system sound of the whole PC1 (where Jackd is installed, and also NodeJS).Is possible to stream the whole system sound throu browser's webSocket ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you have a pc with jack and nodejs as http server.

What you need to do is to install ffmpeg, and follow this instructions: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#jack

You will use ffmpeg within nodejs to stream the output to the browser.

There are several questions about streaming videos and audio with nodejs. You can simply serve a progressive http stream and the browser will play it.

In the end you will not use web-audio api, sockets or WebRTC

Comment: I know FFMPEG, but I use it for audio and video conversion. FFMPEG seems that  attemps to write a file on filesystem and the streaming it with JACKD client, but I have to stream the audio produced by the PC1' system with no latency (so I have no wav file on the PC1 system). The browser on smartphone  have to stream the PC1 system audio in some way

Comment: You don't need to write to a file, you can pipe ffmpeg output directly to the http response. But you'll have a few secs of latency. For near zero latency can only think of webrtc.

Comment: Some examples of WebRTC with FFMPEG?

Comment: Well, as I said as there's no browser on server side you can't simply use the available webrtc javascript api. You can search for webrtc nodejs libraries, but if I remember it correctly only data channels are implemented, you can't work with audio streams. Then, you will need some media stream service like red5 for example or implement it your self using c++ webrtc native, which doesn't have good examples available. This is what I know so far from my researches.